# Android ScrollView doesn't scroll to the bottom completely

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout

I've tried a lot of suggestions like: `android:fillViewport="true"` , changing layout heights to wrap content etc. Some of the solutions worked but they caused editText to overlap toolbar.

I can't scroll to the bottom so I can't see the whole button:

[image]

I'm using a toolbar. And the schema is like that:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
   <Toolbar>
   <ScrollView>
     <ConstraintLayout>
        <TextInput>,<TextView>, <Button> etc.
```

And here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".ui.RegisterActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_register_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/toolbar_title_paddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:text="@string/create_an_account"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_text_size"
        />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_register_activity"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_first_name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_last_name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_last_name"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_first_name">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_last_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_email"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/et_hint_email_id"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_last_name">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_citizenId"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/et_hint_citizenId"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_email">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_citizenId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="11"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_birthdate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number|datetime"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_birthdate"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/et_hint_birthdate"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_citizenId">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_password"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/et_hint_password"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_birthdate">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_confirm_password"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/et_hint_confirm_password"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_password">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_confirm_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_terms_and_condition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_confirm_password">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_terms_and_condition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:checked="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_terms_condition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_terms_condition_marginStart"
                android:text="@string/i_agree_to_the_terms_and_condition"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_terms_and_condition_textSize" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_padding"
            android:text="@string/btn_lbl_register"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_textSize"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_terms_and_condition" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely, that the `ScrollView`s height is `wrap_content` and the content being larger than the available space.

As you are using `ConstraintLayout` as root layout, you can simply set `ScrollView`s height to 0dp and align its bottom edge to `parent`.

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_register_activity"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >
```

Comment: Well, that caused something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5yJw.png

Comment: Please further explain the problem. I don't see whats wrong in that screenshot. Also note, that I've edited my answer, as there was a typo in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView`s always need to be sized to *the space on the screen you want it to occupy* - think of it like a window, and the scrollable content is behind it. You want the window to be a certain size, and then you move the content up and down so you can see different parts of it.

If you make its height `wrap_content`, then it's the same size as the scrollable content, which in this case stretches below the bottom of the screen. So the bottom of the `ScrollView` is off the screen too. It's displaying the entire contents - you just can't see the rest of it. And it won't scroll because it's the same size as its contents - there's nothing extra to scroll.

(If you look at the running app in the *Layout Inspector* tool (not the design view) then you can see exactly what's happening - the `ScrollView` will be taller than the screen)

So you need to do what *pykereaper* says in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73718114/13598222) - set the `ScrollView` to a fixed or constrained size, so it's fully visible. If its contents are bigger than that, it'll scroll to show them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your parent constraint layout's height to "Match_Parent"
2. Set your scroll view bottom constraint to "parent"
3. Set your scroll view height to "0dp"